# git command to add/stage modified files in folders only

Tags: git, dvcs

I've modified several files in a folder and subfolders. I could add the top folder recursively but then i have several subfolders that are untracked, so every time I do the recursive add to stage changes, I have to untrack the subfolders with `git rm -r --cached`. Is there a better way to just stage the modifications that show up in git status, without tracking already explicitly untracked files?

meta-question: is it really a good idea that `git add` means two (or more) things? in this context, if the command to track files (`git add`) were not the same used for stage modifications (`git add`) then i would not have this problem in the first place

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`git add -u` adds only modifications. Also consider adding files which you don't want to track to `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Extra info: `-u` is short for `--update` and it also stages file deletions, not just modifications.

Comment: `git add .` will do the same thing, except that it will ignore tracked files that were deleted.

Comment: Wont `git add .` start tracking untracked files that are not explicitly ignored?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is

```
git commit -a
```

This will let you commit changes only.

Comment: This doesn't just stage files, it also creates a commit. That's not what was asked.